# Visual Basic Registry As Admin Writing Keys To Wrong User

Tags: vb.net, registry, uac

I am trying to use Visual Basic to write keys to a user registry. The program needs to be run as administrator so when the admin account is used for UAC on the non-admin account to run, the program writes the registry on that admin users profile and not the user whose account the application is running on.

I have tried the code below, which writes the value for the key in the current user's software path.

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AppFolder", "Key", "value")
```

However, when I naviagate to that path (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software) on the users profile after execution, that key is not there. However, when I log onto the local admin account that path (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AppFolder) is present.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is the **current user**. If your code is running under the local ministrator account, the current user is the local administrator. Your code is working properly.

Comment: @KenWhite the code is doing its job but is there a different method to target the user whose profile the program is on. I know that since UAC is working off the local admin that is why the reg keys are being written there, but the reg keys are needed for another application on the users profile to function properly.

Comment: This thread help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/16221250/553663

Comment: The short answer to the question in your comment is "no." However if there are registry values needed for the application to run correctly, you could use a GPO (user preferences) to set the needed values for the current user.